# Delete a row in div when click the button using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]

Shown in the picture above, I am trying to delete the row when the `x` button is clicked.

I created a div `<div id="records"> </div>` which I keep appending things to using `$("#records").prepend(new_record)`using jQuery.

The way I implemented the row is:

```
var new_record = username + " " + $("#client-name").val() + $("#reams").val()+ " "+ "<button id='btn-sm'> x </button>"
```

where I just append every part including the button to the variable `new_record`.

However, I am stuck on how to delete this specific row once I click the button, since each button is identical to others. Is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: You can add onclick=somefunction(id). the id is the sequence number and for this you need to add the sequence logic in your code. After this create that somefunction() in which add the logic of remove row

Comment: should this new function be called when $("#btn").click() is called?

Comment: Yes because you call that function on button click. you need to add onclick="funtion_name(id)" inside button tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want a way to identify the entire row so I would wrap each entry in a div or some other element. Then, since the elements are added dynamically, you'll need to use delegated event handling - sensing a click in a parent element and then checking if the real source is from a specific type of child element - which is simple with jQuery. This snippet finds the parent div of the button that is clicked and removes it.

```
$('#records').on('click', 'button', function() {
  $(this).parent('div').remove(); 
});
```

```js
var username = "test";
var new_record = "<div>" + username + " " + $("#client-name").val() + $("#reams").val() + " " + "<button id='btn-sm'> x </button></div>";

$("#records").prepend(new_record);
$("#records").prepend(new_record);
$("#records").prepend(new_record);

$('#records').on('click', 'button', function() {
  $(this).parent('div').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="records"> </div>
```

Comment: Hah, I didn't even really read that - just copy pasta from the question. For this usage I wouldn't even put an id of any sort on there op.